# Bluetooth Compatibility

Tags: pic, bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy, android

In the prototype I'm working, I'm using my phone to communicate with the Bluetooth module RN4871 (https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/RN4871). Now I'm planning to buy a chinese Android industrial tablet to control the machine, but according to the seller, it's Bluetooth version is "Single band Bluetooth, 2.4G".

How can I know if it'll be able to communicate with the RN4871 module? Obs: the tablet only send/receive strings and the RN4871 controls a PIC18F through RX/TX.

Comment: Formally you should find the bluetooth specification versions implemented; notably you make the mistake of calling this "Bluetooth" when it is really "Bluetooth Low Energy" which is a distinct capability not necessarily supported by older/cheaper tablet chips.  Practically speaking, your real issues are likely to be with horrible vendor Android builds which often ship not only with pirated apps but built in viruses or spyware, also perhaps battery vs. mains supply issues.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.